# have to initiate a BLE peripheral every time i use it in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

with CBCentralManager i succesully scan multiple BLE UART devices and connect to them, de devices are stored in the array periphirals[], but when i want to send data to them one by one, only the last one connected i can send succesfully send data to, i solved it by calling blePeripheral?.discoverServices([ParticlePeripheral.BLEService_UUID])before writing data again, but i think this is not the right solution, can someone explain what i am doing wrong?

Below the code i use, the scanning and connecting start by didload
and startCyclus  starts the first device, after the data recieved "didUpdateValueFor" is entered  , getting the data and direct send data to the next peripheral

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

var txCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic?
var rxCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic?
var blePeripheral : CBPeripheral?
var characteristicASCIIValue = NSString()
var Running = false
var currentNode = 0;
var updateService = false
var maxNodes = Int()

class ViewController : UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, UITableViewDelegate{

    //Data
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    var RSSIs = [NSNumber]()
    var data = NSMutableData()
    var peripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []
    var characteristicValue = [CBUUID: NSData]()
    var timer = Timer()
    var characteristics = [String : CBCharacteristic]()
    var teller = 0

    //UI
    @IBOutlet weak var baseTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIBarButtonItem!

   @IBAction func naarRun(_ sender: Any) {
             print("naarRun")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"naarRunView" , sender: self)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "naarRunView") {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewRun
            vc.peripherals = peripherals
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        //print("View Cleared")
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        print("Stop Scanning")
        centralManager?.stopScan()
    }

    /*Okay, now that we have our CBCentalManager up and running, it's time to start searching for devices. You can do this by calling the "scanForPeripherals" method.*/

    func startScan() {
        peripherals = []
        print("Now Scanning...")
        self.timer.invalidate()
        centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [ParticlePeripheral.BLEService_UUID] , options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:false])
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) {_ in
            self.cancelScan()
            self.connectToAllDevices()
        }
    }

    /*We also need to stop scanning at some point so we'll also create a function that calls "stopScan"*/
    func cancelScan() {
        self.centralManager?.stopScan()
        print("Scan Stopped")
        print("Number of Peripherals Found: \(peripherals.count)")
    }

    func disconnectFromDevice () {
        if blePeripheral != nil {
            // We have a connection to the device but we are not subscribed to the Transfer Characteristic for some reason.
            // Therefore, we will just disconnect from the peripheral
            centralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(blePeripheral!)
        }
    }


    func restoreCentralManager() {
        //Restores Central Manager delegate if something went wrong
        centralManager?.delegate = self
    }

    /*
     Called when the central manager discovers a peripheral while scanning. Also, once peripheral is connected, cancel scanning.
     */
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        blePeripheral = peripheral
        teller+=1
        self.peripherals.append(peripheral)
        self.RSSIs.append(RSSI)
        peripheral.delegate = self
        //self.baseTableView.reloadData()
        //if blePeripheral == nil {
            print("Found new pheripheral devices with services")
            print("Peripheral name: \(String(describing: peripheral.name))")
            print("**********************************")
            print ("Advertisement Data : \(advertisementData)")

        //}
    }

    //Peripheral Connections: Connecting, Connected, Disconnected

    //-Connection
    func connectToDevice () {
        centralManager?.connect(blePeripheral!, options: nil)
    }

    func connectToAllDevices(){
        var seconds = 0.0
        for per in peripherals
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
                blePeripheral = per
                print("Connecting naar " + (blePeripheral?.name!)!)
                self.connectToDevice ()
            }
            seconds = seconds + 0.5;
        }
    }

    /*
     Invoked when a connection is successfully created with a peripheral.
     This method is invoked when a call to connect(_:options:) is successful. You typically implement this method to set the peripheral’s delegate and to discover its services.
     */
    //-Connected
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("*****************************")
        print("Connection complete")
        print("Peripheral info: \(String(describing: blePeripheral))")

         //Erase data that we might have
        data.length = 0

        //Discovery callback
        peripheral.delegate = self
        //Only look for services that matches transmit uuid
        peripheral.discoverServices([ParticlePeripheral.BLEService_UUID])


       /*
        //Once connected, move to new view controller to manager incoming and outgoing data
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let uartViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UartModuleViewController") as! UartModuleViewController

        uartViewController.peripheral = peripheral

        navigationController?.pushViewController(uartViewController, animated: true)
 */
    }

    /*
     Invoked when the central manager fails to create a connection with a peripheral.
     */

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to connect to peripheral")
            return
        }
    }

    func disconnectAllConnection() {
        centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(blePeripheral!)
    }

    /*
     Invoked when you discover the peripheral’s available services.
     This method is invoked when your app calls the discoverServices(_:) method. If the services of the peripheral are successfully discovered, you can access them through the peripheral’s services property. If successful, the error parameter is nil. If unsuccessful, the error parameter returns the cause of the failure.
     */
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        print("*******************************************************")

        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let services = peripheral.services else {
            return
        }

        //We need to discover the all characteristic
        for service in services {

            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            // bleService = service
        }
        print("Discovered Services: \(services)")

    }

    /*
     Invoked when you discover the characteristics of a specified service.
     This method is invoked when your app calls the discoverCharacteristics(_:for:) method. If the characteristics of the specified service are successfully discovered, you can access them through the service's characteristics property. If successful, the error parameter is nil. If unsuccessful, the error parameter returns the cause of the failure.
     */

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        print("*******************************************************")

        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {
            return
        }

        print("Found \(characteristics.count) characteristics!")

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            //looks for the right characteristic

            if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(ParticlePeripheral.BLE_Characteristic_uuid_Rx)  {
                rxCharacteristic = characteristic

                //Once found, subscribe to the this particular characteristic...
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: rxCharacteristic!)
                // We can return after calling CBPeripheral.setNotifyValue because CBPeripheralDelegate's
                // didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic method will be called automatically
                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                print("Rx Characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")
            }
            if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(ParticlePeripheral.BLE_Characteristic_uuid_Tx){
                txCharacteristic = characteristic
                print("Tx Characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid)")
            }
            peripheral.discoverDescriptors(for: characteristic)
        }

    }




    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverDescriptorsFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("*******************************************************")

        if error != nil {
            print("\(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }
        guard let descriptors = characteristic.descriptors else { return }

        descriptors.forEach { descript in
            print("function name: DidDiscoverDescriptorForChar \(String(describing: descript.description))")
            print("Rx Value \(String(describing: rxCharacteristic?.value))")
            print("Tx Value \(String(describing: txCharacteristic?.value))")

        }

    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("*******************************************************")

        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error changing notification state:\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")

        } else {
            print("Characteristic's value subscribed")
        }

        if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
            print ("Subscribed. Notification has begun for: \(characteristic.uuid)")
        }
    }



    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("Disconnected")
    }


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error discovering services: error")
            return
        }
        print("Message sent")
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error discovering services: error")
            return
        }
        print("Succeeded!")
    }

    // MARK: - Getting Values From Characteristic
    /** After you've found a characteristic of a service that you are interested in, you can read the characteristic's value by calling the peripheral "readValueForCharacteristic" method within the "didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service" delegate.
     */
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        guard characteristic == rxCharacteristic,
            let characteristicValue = characteristic.value,
            let ASCIIstring = NSString(data: characteristicValue,
                                       encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            else { return }

        characteristicASCIIValue = ASCIIstring
        let ontvangen = String(characteristicASCIIValue)
        let waarde = haalwaarde(recieved: ontvangen)
        print("Value Recieved: " + String(characteristicASCIIValue) )
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: self)
        if(updateService){updateService=false; return}
        if(!waarde.isNumber){print("waarde is no number");return}

        if(Running ){Vervolg()}

    }


    func haalNode(recieved:String)->String{
        //nodenr
        if(recieved.count<10){return "fout";}
        let temp = recieved
        let lengte = recieved.count;
        let start = temp.index(temp.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
        let end = temp.index(temp.endIndex, offsetBy: -(lengte-8))
        let range = start..<end
        let nodeNr = String(temp[range])
        //print("nodeNr=", nodeNr)
        return nodeNr
    }
    func haalwaarde(recieved:String)->String{
        //Reactietijd
        if(recieved.count<10){return "fout"};
        let temp = recieved
        let lengte = recieved.count;
        let start = temp.index(temp.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let end = temp.index(temp.endIndex, offsetBy: -(lengte-7))
        let range = start..<end
        let Reactietijd = String(temp[range])
        //print("\nreactietijd=", Reactietijd)
        return Reactietijd
    }

    func startCyclus(){
        currentNode = 0
        if maxNodes == 0 {return}
        Running = true
        blePeripheral = peripherals[0]
        updateService = true
        blePeripheral?.discoverServices([ParticlePeripheral.BLEService_UUID])
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.writeValue(data: "N  5000G55")
            currentNode += 1
        }

    func Vervolg(){
        print("vervolg")
        if currentNode == maxNodes {Running = false;return}
        blePeripheral = peripherals[currentNode]
        updateService = true
        blePeripheral?.discoverServices([ParticlePeripheral.BLEService_UUID])
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(10)) {
            self.writeValue(data: "N  5000G55")
            currentNode += 1
        }
    }


    // Write functions
    func writeValue(data: String){
        print("schrijfdata  " + String(currentNode))
        let valueString = (data as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        //change the "data" to valueString
        if let blePer = blePeripheral{
            if let txCharacteristic = txCharacteristic {
                blePer.writeValue(valueString!, for: txCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
            }
        }
    }




    /*
     Invoked when the central manager’s state is updated.
     This is where we kick off the scan if Bluetooth is turned on.
     */
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn {
            // We will just handle it the easy way here: if Bluetooth is on, proceed...start scan!
            print("Bluetooth Enabled")
            startScan()

        } else {
            //If Bluetooth is off, display a UI alert message saying "Bluetooth is not enable" and "Make sure that your bluetooth is turned on"
            print("Bluetooth Disabled- Make sure your Bluetooth is turned on")

            let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Bluetooth is not enabled", message: "Make sure that your bluetooth is turned on", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
            alertVC.addAction(action)
            self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    var isNumber: Bool {
        let characters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
        return !self.isEmpty && rangeOfCharacter(from: characters) == nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You only have a single `blePeripheral` property.  If you want to be able to send data to multiple connected peripherals you will need to keep an array of connected peripherals as you do with the discovered peripherals.

Comment: Thank you for your fast comment, I made a new array (peripheralsConnected) and added the devices to it in func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverDescriptorsFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?, but accounted still the same problem. Also tried to add them in "didConnect"

Comment: Have you complete eliminated the `blePeripheral` property?  You should pass the peripheral to `writeValue`. Also, you will probably find it easier to manage what is happening if you create some more classes. Create a class to handle Bluetooth discovery and connection. Create another class to implement your peripheral delegate functions and create one instance per peripheral you are connected to.  Manage one thing at a time instead of trying to do everything in one massive view controller class

Comment: Hallo Paul, will try this later in the week, i will come back on it

Comment: Hi Paul, I have tried everything, but can not use multiple peripherals at the same time. i followed your advice and put the CBCentralManager and connection stuf in a new class, and now make 6 instanced of that class (i have 6 devices) now i can read and write simultaneously to all of the devices, works like a charm now, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your logging is hiding what's really happening.

You reassign `blePeripheral` before each connection, but if any of them take longer than 0.5 seconds, by the time `didConnect` is called, the device that has connected won't be the one that's referred to by `blePeripheral`.

I would suggest removing `blePeripheral` entirely, and explicitly pass the `CBPeripheral` object into `connectToDevice`. Also, in `didConnect`, use the `peripheral` parameter that's passed in.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, I removed blePeripheral and passed the device directly to connect and write  like     self.centralManager.connect(per, options: nil). 
     and writing.  peripheralsConnected[currentNode].writeValue(valueString!, for: txCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse). still no luck, only the last device in the array wil send a message

Comment: the error is 2020-06-06 08:51:54.913569+0200 testpe[1250:252041] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: <CBCharacteristic: 0x281a2f360, UUID = 6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties = 0xC, value = (null), notifying = NO> is not a valid characteristic for peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x280f2c5a0, identifier = 9B654E38-F8BB-28C4-1912-C052A0E7A786, name = RX-Lamp1, state = connected>

Comment: I think the devices are connected alright, the logging is gives Peripheral info: <CBPeripheral: 0x280a48820, identifier = C2FB500D-5864-CA3F-4806-5BA9D1433E1E, name = RX-Lamp2, state = connected>

Discovered Services: [<CBService: 0x282e254c0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E>]

Found 2 characteristics!
Tx Characteristic: 6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E
Rx Characteristic: 6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E
Characteristic's value subscribed
Subscribed. Notification has begun for: 6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E

and the same for RX-Lamp1